# Scheduling Query Store data clean up time

Tags: sql-server, query-store

Is there a way to specify when QueryStore should perform cleanup based on the STALE_QUERY_THRESHOLD_DAYS setting? I am currently experiencing issues when the cleanup kicks in at peak times.

i.e. we have QueryStore set to clear out data older that 30 days, but I want to be able to set it to do this cleanup at 23:00 (during Maintenance hours).
This is not related to the SIZE_BASED_CLEANUP_MODE setting - there is set to AUTO and there is plenty of space available - i.e.

I know of the command to completely clear QueryStore for a Database. I don't want to do that. I want to control when the cleanup operation runs.

I have thoughts about a possible workaround, but would be interested in hearing if anyone knows how SQL Server decides when to do the cleanup, and how I can take control.

Many thanks.